# SQL error trying to delete activities following CRM-20958

Tags: activities

Now that Civi version 4.7.25 has introduced creation_date for activities, I am having SQL errors when I try to create a new activity or delete a recent activity, which results in fatal errors:

> Unknown column 'created_date' in 'field list'

I can't replicate this in the CiviCRM sandbox (http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/), although that is running Civi 4.7.28.

If I run the SQL command in phpmyadmin, then it gives the same error, so I guess there's some problem with the table civicrm_activity since updating to 4.7.25

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by checking that the `civicrm_activity` table does have a `created_date` column.  If not, maybe something went wrong with the upgrade process - which is a bigger issue.

If it does exist, do you have logging enabled?  When you change `civicrm_activity`, a trigger will update the related `log_civicrm_activity` table and if that does not have `created_date` then the original action will fail.  If that is case, you can disable and then re-enable logging at `Administer > System Settings > Misc` which should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Turning off logging solved the problem. It seems like the created_date column had been created ok for the main civicrm_activity table but not for the log_civicrm_activity table. When I tried to re-enable logging, it gave this error (so I'm just going to leave logging off for now):

[nativecode=1194 ** Table 'log_civicrm_activity' is marked as crashed and should be repaired]